# Why my UISearchBar`s frame is changed by the UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchbardelegate, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I write UISearchBar in my TopBar.m like this:

```
_tempSearchBar =[[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(44, 0, 320 - 44, 43)];
_tempSearchBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleDefault;
_tempSearchBar.placeholder=@"搜索";
[self addSubview:_tempSearchBar];
```

the result is like this, it is right.
[image]

and then I write UISearchDisplayController in another class like this:

```
_topBar.tempSearchBar.delegate = self;    
_searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_topBar.tempSearchBar contentsController:self];
[_searchDisplayController setDelegate:self];
[_searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDataSource:self];
```

the UISearchBarDelegate is like this:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISearchBarDelegate
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [_searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:YES];
}
```

when I click the UISearchBar , it show like this , the searchBar`s frame is changed.why?
[image]

when I cancel the UISearchDisplayController it is like this :
[image]

why the frame is changed? The width is changed from 320-44 to 320 by the UISearchDisplayController?
thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The searchBar's frame is changed by the UIKit, so I changed the searchBar's frame back myself.

I changed the searchBar's frame in the below delegate.

One is UISearchBar's delegate:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(44, 0, 320 - 44, 43)];
}
```

Another is UISearchDisplayController's delegate:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller{
    [controller.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(44, 0, 320 - 44, 43)];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView setDelegate:self];
}
```

It can work and I can get the right frame, but when I click the searchBar it will shake a little.

It is not the best way to do it, but it can work. Does anyone have a better method?

Update:
I have debugged the UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController for a few hours, but it has a little bug: When I endEditing the searchBar's width will become 320px, and then will become my width. I can not change the cancelButton's background color. So I wrote a custom SearchDisplayController, with a UISearchBar property and a UITableView property. It works well for me.

Answer (score 12):

UISearchDisplayController expands the search bar to the width of its superview. The simplest solution that I have found is to place the search bar inside another UIView that has the width I am looking for.

Comment: Struggled with this for hours. Wrapped it in a UIView and bam! Always wrap it people!

Comment: A Great answer!  My complete code:
    `UIView *searchContainerView = [UIView  new];  
    [searchContainerView addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];  
    UIBarButtonItem *searchBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]      initWithCustomView:searchContainerView];  
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBarItem;GRect bounds =      self.navigationController.view.frame;  
bounds= CGRectMake(120, 0, bounds.size.width-120, 44);  
    [searchContainerView setFrame:bounds];`

Answer (score 0):

Call the delegate method

```
- (void) searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    [controller.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0,31, 320 , 43)];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView setDelegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can handle the cancel button of searchBar using **- (void)setShowsCancelButton:animated:**
If you do not want to show cancel button (as cancel button will change the frame of searchBar)
just write this in delegate

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{   

    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Updated:

An only possible solution seems to be finding the cancel button from SearchBar view hierarchy and hiding it.

```
for (UIView *possibleButton in searchBar.subviews)
{
    if ([possibleButton isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton *cancelButton = (UIButton*)possibleButton;
        cancelButton.hidden = YES;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , but it does not work ... the cancel button also be showed although I setShowsCancelButton:NO . and the searchBar`s frame also be changed

Comment: thank you very much , I set the cancelButton hidden in the beginEditing delegate and the endEditing delegate , but the cancelButton will show a shink and then hidden . I think the UISearchDisplayController has some bugs(may be features) , so I write a custom SearchDisplayController , it works well for me . Once again thanked

Comment: you can do it in ViewDidLoad itself or where-ever you have created the SearchBar before creating SearchDisplayController.